# How to make input visible only when dropdown selection equals value using KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to KnockoutJS and having trouble getting the text and input "Other Reason" to only be visible when in the dropdown "Other" is selected.  Please help.

```
<div id="reasonPopup" class="selectItems" style="display: none; position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 150px;">
Choose an Reason:<br />
<select data-bind="options: reasons,
optionsText: 'reasonText',
optionsValue: 'reasonValue',
value: chosenReason,
optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>

<p data-bind="with: chosenReason">
    Other Reason: <input data-bind="value: $root.chosenReason, visible: chosenReason == 'Other'" />
    </p>

<p data-bind="with: chosenReason">
    You have chosen <b data-bind="text: $root.chosenReason"></b> 
</p>
<br />
<input type="button" data-bind="click: setReason('OK'), enable: chosenReason" value="OK" />
<input type="button" data-bind="click: setReason('Cancel'), disable: chosenReason" value="Cancel" />
<br />
```

Comment: Looks like something that you should do in the VM. However, you could use the [if binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html).

Comment: Please show us what your view model looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `visible: chosenReason() === 'Other'` in your binding (emphasis on the added parentheses). You are currently comparing the observable to `'Other'` when you intend to compare the current value of the observable.

Another way to do this would be to include another observable in your view model, then bind to that:

```
self.isOtherReason = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.chosenReason() === 'Other';
});
```

It would also make sense to perform your `visible` binding on the `<p>` containing the `<input>`, rather than on the `<input>` directly.

Comment: Timothy, thanks but I've already found that example but it does not work with my setup

Comment: @user3431140 Define "does not work." The problem is very clearly that you're not including the parentheses.

Comment: Fixed... visible: chosenReason() === 'Other'... Doh' the parentheses is the part I need to get used to for knockoutJS... Sorry I can't mark as answer... I don't have enough reputation points to do so

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo-working example of what you are trying to do -

http://jsfiddle.net/FLgyz/

```
<p data-bind="if: chosenReasonId() === 'Other'">
    Other Reason: <span data-bind="text: chosenReasonId"></span>
    </p>

<p data-bind="ifnot: chosenReasonId() === 'Other'">
    You have chosen <b data-bind="text: chosenReasonId"></b> 
</p>
```

Basically you need to use the if binding to compare what you want to show based on criteria.